# Pandas cumsum() grouping output different from sum() grouping output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am getting an unexpected behaviour when using cumsum() in combination with groupby.

Assuming the following data (hourly, different signs, stretching over multiple years):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
start = pd.Timestamp('20191201', tz='Europe/Rome')
end = pd.Timestamp('20200331', tz='Europe/Rome')
index = pd.date_range(start,end,freq='H')
data = np.empty((len(index),))
data[::2] = 3
data[1::2] = -1
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index)
df
```

This is how it would look like, for testing purposes:

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00+01:00   3.00
2019-12-01 01:00:00+01:00   -1.00
2019-12-01 02:00:00+01:00   3.00
2019-12-01 03:00:00+01:00   -1.00
2019-12-01 04:00:00+01:00   3.00
... ...
2020-03-30 20:00:00+02:00   -1.00
2020-03-30 21:00:00+02:00   3.00
2020-03-30 22:00:00+02:00   -1.00
2020-03-30 23:00:00+02:00   3.00
2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00   -1.00
```

Now notice the odd difference between sum() and cumsum() in combination with group by month:

**sum()** --> 3 elements, i.e. one per month

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M')).sum()
2019-12-31 00:00:00+01:00   744.00
2020-01-31 00:00:00+01:00   744.00
2020-02-29 00:00:00+01:00   696.00
2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00   720.00
```

***cumsum()*** --> 1489 elements, i.e. one per hour

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M')).cumsum()
2019-12-01 00:00:00+01:00   3.00
2019-12-01 01:00:00+01:00   2.00
2019-12-01 02:00:00+01:00   5.00
2019-12-01 03:00:00+01:00   4.00
2019-12-01 04:00:00+01:00   7.00
... ...
2020-03-30 20:00:00+02:00   716.00
2020-03-30 21:00:00+02:00   719.00
2020-03-30 22:00:00+02:00   718.00
2020-03-30 23:00:00+02:00   721.00
2020-03-31 00:00:00+02:00   720.00
```

I can see that there are reason why you would want the latter output, but isn't that inconsistent?

Consider the case that the user would like to have the cumulated monthly sum, resetting between years. What code should be used?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing that:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'Y')).cumsum().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M')).last()
```

Are there other / better ways?